# How to automatically detect bugs in a web application?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, findbugs

I have a web application in Vaadin. It has got some forms, search fields, buttons, etc and supported by a SQL database. I have been using `Selenium`, `Sahi Open Source` and some other tools for automated GUI testing.

Problem is: With recording GUI actions for automated testing isn't really useful because it seems more manual work than automated because I need to record the tests manually anyway.

Question is: Is there any better way to test a Web Application? How do you test your web application? Is there any free tool which automatically detects bugs in my web application?

Comment: I would suggest to refine the question a bit. Let's imagine a button in your application has a wrong alignment/position/color, can you suggest any way to automatically spot this problem? It would be better to explicitly specify different types of issues you want to detect.

Comment: I haven't used it or I'd post this as an answer, but try looking into [Applitools](https://applitools.com/), it was the subject of a talk at [GTAC 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLSIUOFhnxEiCWGsN9t5A-XOhRbmz54IS1&v=euJ2OrlBEqQ)

Answer (score 1):

This won't be possible unless someone will invent sentient AI and even that might not be enough. In our company we have separate QA department (they're intelligent human beings) and they keep asking questions like "how we're supposed to test this flow" and "is this the expected response".

Without test that is aware of the business flow that you're limited to what bots do - randomly crawl trough site and try to get "500 page" and that is not enough. If you're tired of writing tests you can:

- Use static code analysis tool (like jshint) to check if your code is written in "best practices" way
- Use your users as testers (have streamlined release process, and mechanism of reporting error so you can address production bug as quickly as possible)
- Hire someone to write the test for you

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to test software.  None of them are fully automatic; they all require that actual behavior be compared against expected behavior, and expected behavior cannot be automatically inferred by a machine but must instead be prescribed and defined by humans, and then translated to a language that a machine can understand and use to determine whether it matches the actual behavior.

Here is a starting point to start reading about other ways to test your software:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_testing